# Is it recommended to keep a Giphy API key secret?

Tags: javascript, giphy, giphy-api

I'm using Giphy's API and currently have a development key. I am looking to deploy my site but don't know whether it is a public facing key or a private one, and cannot find an answer online nor after asking them directly.

Comment: Generally if an API key was given specifically to your user account, it should be kept private. Requests to the api with that key should come from your account, not everyone else. This at least pertains to production api keys, not test/sand keys

Answer (score 5):

> Here is the official response to this question from GIPHY:
>
> > GIPHY APIs are designed to be used on the client side (and hence the API key too). You should go ahead and use it that way. Once development is complete - please apply for Production access for the key through the Developer Dashboard, this removes Rate limits associated with a beta key, so you don't have to worry about high traffic.
> > Lastly, and most importantly - GIPHY has monitors setup for API key abuse and we'll reach out to you if anything happens. We definitely don't want you to worry about it.

[From here](https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-js/issues/120#issuecomment-680988917)

Seems shouldn't be worrying about it.

Answer (score 4):

While I generally tend to agree with Jay's answer, after reviewing their [introduction](https://developers.giphy.com/docs/) and the specific javascript sample it seems to me that this key should be used from the browser and as a result it is practically a public key.
I would assume that later on in the process, to avoid abuse with production API key, they might only serve requests coming from a domain you registered along with that key.
Development key is anyhow for limited testing purposes as far as I understand so that's less of an issue if there's no registered domain for that.